# I couldn't run mongo service in Mac OS

Tags: python, mongodb, macos, pip

After upgrading the python version 2 to 3.8.5. A mongo service is not working. Getting below errors.

```
AMM00361:bin macuser1$ mongod
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongod
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

openssl version is OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

Please share your thoughts!

Comment: yes it is mongodb

Comment: What have you tried to solve so far?

Comment: Actually I have installed the Elastalert and then installed dependent softwares like pip and python 3.8. After upgrading the python 2 to 3.8 I am unable to run the mongo server

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall mongodb (`brew reinstall`) or switch to the other versions of openssl package (`brew switch`)?

Comment: Did you solve it?